# switch case inside linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, switch-statement

I have a linq query like

```
 var tmp = (from t in db.sometable
            where (bunch of conditions)
            group t by new { t.somefield} into g
            select new
            {                               
                Name = g.Key.someobject.Name,
                xColor = g.Sum(a => (int?)a.LineItems.Where(m => m.Product == "x" && m.Color == true)
                                                     .Sum(m => m.Quantity)),
                xBW = g.Sum(a => (int?)a.LineItems.Where(m => m.Product == "x" && m.Color == false)
                                                  .Sum(m => m.Quantity))    
            })
```

Now I want to optimize this query. If I had to write a stored procedure I would have written some thing like:

```
if(a.LineItems.Product == 'x')
{
   if(m.Color == true)
     xColor++;
   else
     xBW++;
}
```

so that I get aggregated value in one scan. Basically I wanted to optimize this query to avoid multiple scans.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Yes thanks for pointing it out, its now corrected.

Comment: You can add switch case by introducing the curly brackets inside the linq query and updating a global variable, thus using it as final value, but I am not sure how would that be efficient, since that too will process each inside IEnumerable<IGrouping> created due to Groupby

Answer (score 1):

check out this simple code snippet in `Linqpad`, which does the way you expect, for running in visual studio, remove the `Dump` method call. I have simplified the class structure a bit for a simple demo, it is just a `POCO`, not a `complex type` containing another `list` inside

```
void Main()
{
    var testList = Test.CreateList();

    var tmp = (from t in testList
               group t by new { t.Name } into g
               select new
               {
                   Name = g.Key.Name,
                   xColor = g.Sum(a =>
                   {
                       if (a.Product == "x" && a.Color == true)
                           return a.Quantity;
                       return 0;
                   }),
                    xBW = g.Sum(a =>
                   {
                       if (a.Product == "x" && a.Color == false)
                           return a.Quantity;
                       return 0;
                   })
               });

    tmp.Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Product { get; set;}

    public bool Color { get; set;}

    public int? Quantity { get; set;}

    public static List<Test> CreateList()
    {
        return new List<Test>()
        {
          new Test {Name="A",Color = true,Product="x",Quantity=5},
          new Test {Name="A",Color = true,Product="x",Quantity=5},
          new Test {Name="A",Color = true,Product="x",Quantity=5},
          new Test {Name="B",Color = true,Product="x",Quantity=5},
          new Test {Name="B",Color = true,Product="x",Quantity=5},
          new Test {Name="B",Color = true,Product="x",Quantity=5}         
        };
    }
}
```

However whether this is efficient or not can still be debated

Comment: this is same as my question, as answer here is doing it in two separate query not one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing that would work in SQL. If there's a subset of data (lines matching particular criteria) then select those first into an array. Then you can execute your larger query against that subset.